# How to reload a program in C?

Tags: c

For example I have a program that adds two numbers. Once I input the two numbers and calculate their sum, I want to go back to the beginning of main, and be able to give other 2 numbers. This is a minimal example, using a simple loop wont work because I am working on a program that has over 30 different functions in use.

Comment: Learn about *loops*.

Comment: @EugeneSh. as I said, some simple loops wont work

Comment: I cannot possibly see why a loop would not work.

Comment: How a number of functions affect the enclosing loop?

Comment: `over 30 different functions in use` to calculate the sum of two numbers?

Comment: You can use a `goto`

Comment: @Broman Why not go all out and recursively call `main`?

Comment: @ChristianGibbons Because it is undefined behavior.

Comment: @Broman Are you sure about that?  My cursory research shows it to be legal in C, while being illegal in C++.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons You seem to be right.

Answer (score 0):

What about a thread that handles this feature of the program? You can move the sum functionality exclusively to a thread and loop it there.